# Nodejs module oracled cannot find LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, node.js, oracle, centos6

I'm getting the following error in my nodejs script using the oracledb module on a Centos 6 VM:

```
Error: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

We're using the full Oracle client. My google searches have led me to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` being the problem. It is set in `/etc/profile.d/` in an oracle script, and I can see it in my linux user's `env` output. But when I check `process.env` within the node script, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is simply not there. (If I add other variables to my `/etc/profile.d` script, those test variables appear in `process.env`)

The other weirdness is that when I run the script as `root`, the variable gets set properly and the script executes as expected.

So why is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` disappearing when my non-root user runs the script?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain how you are invoking the script.  If you are sudo-ing, do you need to call a shell script that sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH before invoking node?

Comment: When I use the non-root user, I just run the script without sudo. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is only set in /etc/profile.d and not anywhere else.

Comment: Did you actually 'export' it? How are you invoking node?